# Sort after values in an Object inside HashMap

Tags: java

I had to code my own ´Filter` for a medal table, which I put in a

`HashMap <String, MedalsOfCountry> unsortedList`.

The `key` is the code of a country, for example:"USA" and the `MedalsOfCountry` is the object for the specific country with the fields: `goldCount`, `silverCount`, `bronzeCount`. `MedalsOfCountry` is a static inner class, which I coded and looks like this:

```
static class MedalsOfCountry extends Filter {
    int goldCount;
    int silverCount;
    int bronzeCount;
    Medal medalType;

    MedalsOfCountry(Medal m, int count) {
        medalType = m;
        if (medalType == Medal.GOLD) {
            goldCount += count;
        } else if (medalType == Medal.SILVER) {
            silverCount+= count;
        } else {
            bronzeCount += count;
        }
    }

    public int compareTo(MedalOfCountry medals) {
        if(this.goldCount == medals.goldCount) {
            return this.silverCount - medals.silverCount;
        } else if(this.silverCount == medals.silverCount) {
            return this.bronzeCount - medals.bronzeCount;
        }
        return this.goldCount - medals.goldCount;
    }
```

Anyway I tried to sort my HashMap like this:

```
Map<String, MedalsOfCountry> sortedList = new TreeMap<String, MedalsOfCountry>(new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String land1, String land2) {
            return unsortedList.get(land1).compareTo(unsortedList.get(land2));
        }
```

Why does my sorting not work?

Comment: You are trying to sort it by the country(Key) or the `MedalsOfCountry`?

Comment: A TreeMap has its **keys** sorted, not its values. If you want to sort by values, create a List<Map.Entry<String, MedalsOfCountry>>, and sort this list. Note that the MedalsOfCountry class doesn't make much sense, since it's supposed to count the number of medals of gold, silver and bronze for one country, but there is no way to increment the count: either goldCount, silverCount or bronzeCount will be equal to 1, and the others will always be equal to 0. Having a medalType field in a class supposed to count the three kinds of medals doesn't make much sense either.

Comment: I try to sort it by `MedalsOfCountry`, for example if the "USA" has 46 gold medals and "CHN" has 43 gold medals, then it would be sorted like this: 1. USA - 46 gold 22 silver 21 bronze , 2. CHN - 43 gold 22 silver 21 bronze

Comment: If you are trying to sort by the number of medals of a country, you should first think how are you going to sort it. If its only by the by the number of gold medals or is it by all the medals. If all the types of medals, you should consider giving a weightage to a medal type. So depending on the medal type, weightage and count, you can define a sorting criteria.

Comment: Your `MedalsOfCountry` should probably be initialized using constructor like `new MedalsOfCountry(goldMedals, silverMedals, bronzeMedals)` and have getters for each medal type like `getGoldMedals` and so on. This way you could write comparator like `Comparator.comparingInt(MedalsOfCountry::getGoldMedals).thenComparingInt(MedalsOfCountry::getSilverMedals).thenComparingInt(MedalsOfCountry::getBronzeMedals)`. This comparator will first test amount of gold medals, then in case of same amount of gold test silver, and in case of also equal silver check amount of bronze.

Comment: @LeoN it's just how many gold medals a country has. if the gold medal count of two countries is identical, then it will compare my the silver medal amount and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) is sorted by keys:

> The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

So using a TreeMap would not be the best choice in your case. You could either use a `LinkedHashMap` or changing your map to a `List`.

A [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) is sorted by insertion order:

> This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order).

```
Map<String, MedalsOfCountry> sorted = unsorted.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted((entry0, entry1) -> entry0.getValue().compareTo(entry1.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (v0, v1) -> {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("duplicate keys are not possible here");
    }, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

To improve this I would recommend to implement the [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface in your Object class:

```
static class MedalsOfCountry implements Comparable<MedalsOfCountry> {
    int goldCount;
    int silverCount;
    int bronzeCount;

    MedalsOfCountry(int count) {
        goldCount += count;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MedalsOfCountry medals) {
        int compareGold = this.goldCount - medals.goldCount;
        if (compareGold != 0) {
            return compareGold;
        }
        int compareSilver = this.silverCount - medals.silverCount;
        if (compareSilver != 0) {
            return compareSilver;
        }
        return this.bronzeCount - medals.bronzeCount;
    }
}
```

You then can use the following to create the sorted map:

```
Map<String, MedalsOfCountry> sorted = unsorted.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (v0, v1) -> {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("duplicate keys are not possible here");
    }, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Additionally you can improve your `compareTo()` method by using a comparator to define multiple steps:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(MedalsOfCountry medals) {
    return Comparator.comparingInt(MedalsOfCountry::getGoldCount)
        .thenComparingInt(MedalsOfCountry::getSilverCount)
        .thenComparingInt(MedalsOfCountry::getBronzeCount)
        .compare(this, medals);
}
```

To also can use the `Comparator.reversed()` method to reverse the order of your stream:

```
Map<String, MedalsOfCountry> sorted = unsorted.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry<String, MedalsOfCountry>::getValue).reversed())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (v0, v1) -> {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("duplicate keys are not possible here");
    }, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This gives me a ascending order instead of a descending order

Comment: You can use the comparator `reversed()` method for that. I also noticed that your `compareTo()` method was not comparing correctly and updated it in my post. I also added some more details in my answer.